# I am getting wrong output in my cpp program

Tags: c++, string, getline, substr

```
 while(t--){
    string str, token, dummy;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin ,str);
    int pos = str.find(' ');
    token = str.substr(pos+1);
    str = str.substr(0, 3);
    cout << str << " " <<  token << endl;
}
```

On giving input as:
add hackerrank
add hacker
find hac
find hak

output comming as:
add hackerrank
dd hacker
ind hac
ind hak

I'm missing first char of my input from second line.

Comment: This looks like English but the more I read it the greater the distance becomes between me and low Earth orbit.

Answer (score 0):

From istream [ignore()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) *[emphasis added]*

> basic_istream& ignore( std::streamsize count = 1, int_type delim = Traits::eof() );
>
> **Extracts and discards characters** from the input stream until and including delim.

The default value of `count` is `1`. So, it is ignoring `1` character from input stream as you are calling it without any parameter.

You are observing this behaviour of ignoring first character of input from *second* line because you might have given some input value before `while` loop (may be input value for `t`, like this - `cin >> t`) and hit the enter button which is leaving the stray `\n` in input stream. The first execution of `cin.ignore()` eating that stray `\n` character from input stream and from second input string onwards it eating up the first character of your input.

To solve this problem, you can simply add `cin.get()` just after the input value giving before entering `while` loop and remove `cin.ignore()` from loop body.

Comment: Thank you so much for such immediate feedback and for the clear explanation. That means a lot. My problem solved